# Need help figuring out why my Reverse String c++ program is breaking

Tags: c++, xcode, string, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string just as a simple exercise to prepare myself for interviews. I wanted to write a program that takes keyboard input and reverses it, in c++. For some reason I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (in Xcode) at the line "cin >> myString;" I suspect that I am doing something pretty stupid, but I could really use some help in finding out what's wrong, and how I should fix it. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *myString = nullptr;
    char *revString = nullptr;
    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    cin >> myString;

    cout << endl;

    size_t myLength = strlen(myString);

    for (int i = 0; i < myLength; i++)
    {
        revString[i] = myString[myLength -1 - i];
    }

    cout << "Your string, reversed, has become: ";
    printf(revString);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `char *myString = nullptr;` - `MyString` doesn't point to anything.  Is there a reason you aren't using `std::string`?

Comment: You're assigning a value to an uninitialized memory space with `cin >> myString;`. You need to allocate space for the string using either `char myString[50]; cin >> myString;` or `char* myString = new char[50]; cin >> myString; // use myString; delete[] myString.`

Comment: @ViteFalcon: Introducing a buffer overflow vulnerability isn't the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: `cin >> [char*]` is always wrong. No matter how much memory you have allocated, the user can always enter more characters than that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Whether or not it causes buffer overflow is another question. What I was simply trying to answer was that the memory had to be allocated. Stop nit-picking!

Comment: @Vite Falcon: Sorry, there's no correct solution with preallocated memory that will be safe. End of story. `cin >> [char*]` is *always* wrong, unless you can somehow guarantee that you, and only you, have full control over what is sent to cin in a particular process. That dreaded `operator>>(char*)` overload should be turned off by default as it promotes hacks that IMHO crazy people then argue are somehow OK. There *is no way* to allocate memory properly for `operator>>(char*)` feeding from `cin`. `cin >> [std::string]` is the right way to do it.

Comment: @KubaOber: Ever wondered how it is done in C, which doesn't have std::string? I know his question is C++, but you have multiple ways to do things, end of story. I didn't want to give him a lesson on memory management and what's the best way to read a string, rather, point him out that he's missing memory allocation (in any form). As simple as that.

Comment: Someone who doesn't have the most basic knowledge of memory allocation is going for a C++ job interview! I know there's a world wide shortage of devs, but I'm shocked. (And also can't concoct a simple string reverse algorithm).

Comment: @ViteFalcon: In C, you'd use `fread` or similar, specifying the maximum amount to read and handling truncation in some way. That's not an option if you want to use `>>` to read from a C++ stream; using it on a fixed-size buffer is plain wrong, since there is no way to avoid a buffer overflow.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: That's just one way of doing it. I'm sure we all started learning reading it using `scanf`. Don't be shy to admit you too started with that and not with fread (assuming you started with C). Likewise, he started off using 'C' way of strings. Let him learn it well to know the pitfalls. Nowadays people expect others to learn the right thing the right way, without even the slightest knowledge of why it's being done the right way. There was a reason before the 'right' thing came by. Let him learn the low-level stuff as well, again, assuming he has that inclination.

Comment: @ViteFalcon: Thanks for all your help. I am not actually going to be working for quite a bit, I'm still fairly new to programming, especially in c++ (more experience with C#). I fixed the lack of allocation, so now it works for all strings except ones with spaces in them (like "my string"). Is there a way to fix that? It looks like scanf won't save spaces either, so I'm not too sure what to use to read keyboard input... the code I currently have is [here](http://pastebin.com/0WqTBD8k)

Comment: That is because "my string" gets treated as two separate strings. Look into `cin.getline()` function to read a line.

Answer (score 5):

No memory has been allocated for `myString` or `revString`. You need to allocate memory using `new[]` or use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). If you use `new[]`, or use a stack allocated array of `char`, then you will need to limit the number of characters read to avoid buffer overrun. Using `std::string` removes this responsibility from you as `std::string` will dynamically grow to the required size.

Unsure if this is a learning exercise or STL algorithms are not permitted but if they were you could use [`std::reverse()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to reverse a `std::string` (see example here http://ideone.com/7LZHs).

Comment: This "need to limit the number of characters read" should not be brushed under the carpet. It is *the* key requirement that can almost ever be fulfilled when reading from `cin`!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, hmjd! Now the code works fine for a string with no spaces (i.e. examplestring), but myString will not save anything after a space (i.e. "example string"). I think this is a problem with cin. How do I fix it? Do I have to abandon cin? Here is my code:
    `string myString;
    string revString;
    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    cin >> myString;`

Comment: @chantninja, use `std::getline(cin, myString);`

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two problems with your code: you are writing to a character buffer that you did not allocate, and you are constructing a palindrome from the second half of the string, rather than reversing it.

Since this is C++, you shouldn't use C strings, and prefer C++ strings instead (`std::string` is the type that you need). You should also swap the characters at the two ends of the string, rather than simply assigning the character from the ending part to a character from the initial part of the string. The most fitting function for swapping characters is `std::swap`.

```
string str = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
for (int i = 0, j = str.size()-1 ; i < j ; swap(str[i++], str[j--]))
    ;
cout << str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for myString. Use a static array or a new statement.

```
char myString[512];
char * myString = new char[512];
```

Comment: No, use `std::string` so you can read the input without risking a buffer overflow.

Comment: Agreed for normal use, pick std::string. But the man is trying to learn how to reverse a string. So, recommending plain char arrays.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You're hoping the baby to start running before he starts to make his first steps. Let him learn his way through! Jeez!

Comment: @ViteFalcon: That's where the problem is: teaching the wrong and unsafe way of implementing common constructs to people who are learning and don't know any better. For all I know the asker will keep coding like that, and your credit card or other sensitive data will get leaked one day as someone exploits it. In reality such bad code tends to survive various eradication efforts. Yours is as bad of an advice as it ever gets. How is using `std::string` harder than using a naked C array?!

Comment: @KubaOber: I'm sure if he codes like that for his interview he's never going to get anywhere near the field of programming credit card details or any sensitive data. Otherwise his interviewer must be really bad, which case it's inevitable anyway. Sooner or later, he's going to figure out C strings are not as easy to work with and resort to std::string. He started off with C string, so why not let him learn that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to cram data into a pointer that doesn't point to memory you can use.

This line declares a pointer to a character and sets it to `nullptr`:

```
char *myString = nullptr;
```

But that's it - it doesn't point at any writable memory, so there's nowhere valid for the input to go. `cin` doesn't do any sort of memory allocation for you.

One way to fix it is to statically allocate your string:

```
char myString[SOME_SIZE] = "";
```

Where `SOME_SIZE` is a constant value big enough to hold your input string.

Or you can declare it as a std::string instead, as was suggested by another poster. In C++ this is the safer/better way to do it to avoid any possible overflows.

```
std::string myString;
```